# Finding combinations given constraints

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, computational-complexity

I have a list of variables `[a,b,c,d...]` where each variable is either 0 or 1. The number of permutations here is $2^n$ and so I believe the complexity of getting all possibilities would be $O(2^n)$.

If I have certain exclusions from the list, is there a way of getting all possible combinations which is less than $O(2^n)$. For example, if I knew that `[b,c,d]` cannot be `[0,0,1]`, I think this would remove $\frac{1}{8}$ of all solutions (a fairly significant amount when $n$ is large). So is there a way of generating all possibilites without just generating all permutations of `[a,b,c,d...]` and only keeping the ones which work. Many thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you are hoping for.  The list of values is just the integers from $0$ to $2^n-1$ written in base $2$ so there is no difficulty enumerating them (and you can't enumerate them any faster than you can enumerate those integers since it is the same problem). If you exclude some combination(s) from $[b,c,d]$ then solve the problem for $n-3$ and insert the allowed block(s) into the appropriate slot.

Comment: Thanks for your response and I see what you're saying but I think it would get more complicated if `b` appears in multiple exclusions. Let's say `[b,c,d]` cannot be `[0,0,1]` and `[a,b,c]` cannot be `[1,1,1]`. Would you still be able to use your improvement, given the variables appear in multiple exclusions?

Comment: Well, yes.  More complicated exclusions would entail more complicated procedures.  I don't believe you'll come up with a general procedure that handles every conceivable sort of exclusion.